# Require recent MFA on Google Signin

Tags: openid-connect, google-signin

I need to ensure that a user signing in with *Google Signin* was authenticated recently with multi factor authentication. Looking through the [OpenID connect request parameters](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#RequestParameters) there are some things like promising for this: `acr_values` and `max_age`.

During testing `max_age` seems useless. I'm still just authenticated with my existing cookie, rather than being *actively authenticated* by Google. Using this request parameter does make the `id token` contain this json

```
"amr": [
    "rba"
  ],
```

which according to this [rfc](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-jones-oauth-amr-values-02.html) means the *authentication method reference* was *risk based authentication*. It turns out this always returns `rba`. If logout and then sign back in it returns `rba` and not `pwd mfa` like I was expecting.

I don't see any values defined for `acr_values`.

So...

Is it possible to:

- Force a user to re-authenticate with Google Sign (e.g. no cookie
  based auth)?
- Determine if the user authenticated with password or
  multifactor?
- Determine when the user authenticated? (Currently
  `auth_time` seems to get set to the time Google saw my session
  cookie when I initiate the sign in flow)
- Request that a user authenticate with MFA?